# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Byte in NIFI

Tags: mysql, json, apache-nifi

`{"edit_history_tweet_ids":["1607615574473080832"],"id":"1607615574473080832","text":"Twitter bms with this dumb ass update "}`

This is my flowfile
and i wanna INSERT that mysql DB using PutDatabaseRecord

[table_desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn63v.png)
it's my table description (ver 8.0)

PutDatabaseRecord Process' bulletin say `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Byte`
I think 'edit_history_tweet_ids' column is problem
What should I do?

I tried that JSON flowfile `ConvertJsontoSql` and `PutSql`
but after `ConvertJsontoSql` Processor, `edit_history_tweet_ids` column's data disappears

[after_convertjsontosql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02bZ1.png)

when INSERT valid generated flowfile, it is successfully done.

[updated_attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDl7o.png)

Comment: I suggest using a `EvaluateJsonPath` processor to attribute (`sql.args.1.value` -> `$.text`)

Comment: does your file always contain one record?

Answer (score 1):

It was solved by converting text to escapeJSON using UpdateRecord and changing it to csv format.
It seems to be solved by setting text to string instead of array.